# Understanding NewRelic Graph

Tags: php, drupal-7, newrelic

I have integrated my site with Newrelic. My website is build in Drupal 7 and have webservices. There are many webservices return response in milliseconds. But when I see the Newrelic graph it shows the exact response time along Y-Axis but along X-Axis, it shows exact two minutes for every call every time. Which, I think, means the request has been generated e.g. at 02:25 will be completed at 02:27 which is obviously not correct. Point is am I looking into the graph wrong way? I don't understand why X-Axis shows me continuous 2 minutes taken by a request. Graph is attached for reference
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X axis shows response times *over time*. At ~22:46, the server was idle. At ~22:47, it took ~150ms to respond. At ~22:49, it was back down to idle. The Y axis shows (average) response times. The X axis has nothing to do with the response time of one individual request. If the width of a spike on the X axis had anything to do with the actual response time, you couldn't see anything, since one spike would be thinner than 1 pixel.